# Revert from a file to one of the original using patch/diff

Tags: shell, diff, reverse, patch

I received an exercise to where i have to recreate a file based on a file.diff and first.txt

I need to recreate second.txt (file is not given) on base of the previous 2 files.

in my logic it should be something if i write it mathematical file.diff - first.txt = second.txt but i don't know how to combine this with patch and diff.

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Comment: The tool you're looking for is `patch`. From its man's synopsis : "patch - apply a diff file to an original"

Comment: thank you i tried patch first.txt file.diff

but it rewrite the first.txt with the content of second.txt is there a way to keep first.txt unchanged and save the difference straight in to second.txt?

Comment: `-o` / `--output` lets you define an output file. Note that I've never used the tool, I'm just skimming its man which you should take the habit to do